# Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.2.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

Tags: java, android, gradle, build.gradle, android-studio-3.0

I was on flamingo then i faced this error then i updated android studio to headgehog but still facing same error. I have tried almost every solution on internet but nothing worked for me.

whenever i create new project I'm getting this error.

configuration i have:

- latest java jdk
- gradle 8.1
- AGP version 8.2.0

getting this popup again and again

[image]

**error i got while sync:**

```
Build file 'C:\Users\Mohit Dhote\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication2\build.gradle.kts' line: 5

Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.2.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.2.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.2.0')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Google
    MavenRepo
```

here is more info:

[image]

I have tried changing gradle version,
updated to latest jdk version,
tried almost everything available on internet

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the line `gradlePluginPortal()` in your `pluginManagement.repositories` block in `settings.gradle`:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Comment: I think gradlePluginPortal() was already there in settings. gradle. finally i fixed this error by reinstalling android studio with standard settings,

Answer (score 0):

I have fix this error by **reinstalling android studio with standard setting** none of the given method worked for me i have tried everything available on internet.  but before that you have to uninstall the complete android studio.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had used the same versions and faced to the same problem. I searched a lot in stackoverflow and other websites and after 2 hours I found a solution for my problem and that was setting proxy.
I used fodev.org host
It is really simple just follow this path :

**File>Setting>Appearance & Behavior>System Settings>HTTP Proxy**

select manual proxy and set host name and port as below :

```
Host Name : fodev.org
port Number : 8118
```